# Parsing a linear system from file

Tags: python, list

In a text file, i enter a linear system with 3 equations. (ex: a1x+b1y+c1z=r1, a2x+b2y+c2z=r2.. etc)

I want to solve this system using matrix rules. For this, i have to parse the system into 2 vectors.

[[a1,b1,c1],[a2,b2,c2],[a3,b3,bc3]] and [r1,r2,r3]

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as fd: s = list(map(lambda x: [int(coef) for coef in x.split('+')] , fd.read().replace(' ','').replace('x','') \
                                             .replace('y','').replace('z','').replace('=','+').replace('-','+').split('\n')))
```

For now I have done the code above, but what i parse is [[a1,b1,c1,r1],[a2,b2,c2,r2],[a3,b3,c3,r3]]

Comment: Using algebra, you probably want to use numpy. As you are not using it right now, much depends on your own matrix-definition (list of lists). What's the problem in extracting and removing every last-value into some new flat list (one loop)? Then you left-hand-side is a list of all the previously transformed lists (1 line of code).

Comment: I will solve problem with/and without numpy but for now I have to parse the file . I don't know how to remove every last value into a new list (that's what i desire but don't know how to do it).

Comment: Then read some basic python tutorial. Either create new data and drop the last element of each list (e.g. slicing with [:-1]), or use del to remove from a list.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution would be:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f: equations = f.read().splitlines()

abc, r = [], []
for i in equations:
    data = i.split()
    abc.append([int(data[0].replace('x','')),int(data[2].replace('y','')),int(data[4].replace('z',''))])
    r.append(int(data[6]))
```

**Note**: The solution of course assumes that if *any of a,b or c is 0* even then the equation will be in the form of: e.g. `5x + 3y + 0z = 5`

Comment: For r it's ok but I don't exactly need a,b,c ( i need only one list like [[a1,b1,c1],[a2,b2,c2],[a3,b3,c3]]). How do i do that in your way?

Comment: @zowie I updated the answer, check now. Also if it solves your issue consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

If `l` is `[[a1,b1,c1,r1],[a2,b2,c2,r2],[a3,b3,c3,r3]]`, then `[a[:3] for a in l]` is `[[a1, b1, c1], [a2, b2, c2], [a3, b3, c3]]`, and `[a[-1] for a in l]` is `[r1, r2, r3]`